# Non-Hermitian measurement operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, measurements, density-operator

I am familiar with the von Neumann projection postulates but I don't know how one can write a non-Hermitian measurement operator using von Neumann measurement model. Does anyone can help?

Comment: Why should that be possible?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but measuring non-Hermitian operators are always possible. The only condition one require is that $\sum_i M_i^\dagger M_i = I$, where $M_i$ is the measurement matrices and $I$ is the identity matrix. The question here is that how one can write $M_i$ using von Neumann measurement model.

Comment: Can you cite a physical system for which the individual Mi are observable?  Or is it a theoretical construct, i.e. that sum combination is Hermitian and does not violate the postulates of QM?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for these claims? The most general form of measurement, that I know of, are [POVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM), for which $M_i$ are Hermitian operators.

Comment: @gIS: For a general POVM, the only condition is $\sum_i M_i^\dagger M_i=I$, and here $M_i$ need not be Hermitian.

Comment: @gIS a general POVM consists of a set of positive operators (which are Hermitian to give real eigenvalue) composed with a set of unitary evolutions (different for each outcome). It is the unitary evolution part which makes the full M operators non-Hermitian in general. I will try to find reference - it is called polar decomposition theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: Original reference Choi (1975) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379575900750

Comment: In physics we are actually quite often interested in measuring non-Hermitian operators. Those may arise as matrix elements of certain operators (probably Hermitian themselves) between different states. Consider, for example, the expression for the elastic form factor of the hadron, $F(q) =\dfrac{1}{P^++P^{\prime +}} \langle P|J^+|P'\rangle$. Same for decay constants.

Answer (score 2):

von Neumann measurements are a special case of the more general measurements you describe.

You are correct a general quantum measurement is described by a set of non-Hermitian matrices $M_i$ with $\sum_i   M_i ^\dagger M_i = I$. I will show how the general prescription reduces to von-Neumann.

In the general measurement scheme the probability of measuring outcome $i$ is given by

$$p_i = Tr[M_i \rho M_i^\dagger] $$

The new density matrix given measurement outcome $i$ is given by

$$ \rho_i = \frac{M_i \rho M_i^\dagger}{p_i}  $$

In the von Neumann case the $M_i$ are projection operators

$$ M_i = M_i^\dagger =  \lvert i \rangle \langle i \rvert $$

Apply this in the general formulas above you get

$$ p_i = Tr [ \lvert i \rangle \langle i \rvert \rho \lvert i \rangle \langle i \rvert ]  = \langle i \rvert \rho \rvert i \rangle $$

and $$ \rho_i = \lvert i \rangle \langle i \rvert$$

i.e. wavefunction collapse to state $\lvert i \rangle$.